# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'response'

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have an error handling module that I'm using in my main script to make requests to an API. I want to return "response" and "data" to use in the main script. It works up until trying to print "response". Apologies for inconsistencies, I am obviously still learning. And I won't learn without making a few mistakes first. I appreciate constructive criticism.

**my_module**

```
import requests
import json

def errorHandler(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
        status = response.status_code
        data = response.json()
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
        print "Timeout error.\n"
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        print "Connection error.\n"
    except ValueError:
        print "ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded.\n"
    else:
        if response.status_code == 200:
            print "Status: 200 OK \n"
        elif response.status_code == 400:
            print "Status: " + str(status) + " error. Bad request."
            print "Correlation ID: " + str(data['correlationId']) + "\n"
        else:
            print "Status: " + str(status) + " error.\n"

    return response
    return data
```

**my_script**

```
errorHandler("https://api.weather.gov/alerts/active")

print "Content type is " + response.headers['content-type'] +".\n" #expect geo+json

# I need the data from the module to do this, but not for each get request
nwsId = data['features'][0]['properties']['id']
```

**error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_script.py", line 20, in <module>
    print errorHandler.response
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'response'
```

Comment: Did you mean `print errorhandler()`? (Your function only returns `response`).

Comment: 2 returns, only the first one will be returned, try `return response, data` and use the function accordingly, it will return a tuple now

Comment: Why do you set the `status` variable but never use it? Maybe you want `return status, data`?

Comment: @Barmar It is used. This was an abbreviated version to shorten the code. I will edit to show you exactly how and why I need multiple objects returned.

Comment: Fix the indentation in your edited code. Everything after the first `else:` needs to be indented.

Comment: @Barmar Copy and paste error. That part works.

Comment: Anyway, all that extra code is irrelevant to the problem. The answer I posted is still correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to return multiple values, you return them as a tuple in a single statement:

```
return response, data
```

Then in the caller, you assign them to variables with a tuple assignment:

```
response, data = errorHandler("https://api.weather.gov/alerts/active")
print "Content type is " + response.headers['content-type'] +".\n"
nwsId = data['features'][0]['properties']['id']
```

However, your function will not work correctly if any of the exceptions occur. If there's an exception, it won't set the variables `response` or `data`, so when it tries to return them it will get an error.

Comment: Actually, response returns `Content type is application/problem+json`.
For data, I would still have an error message to go off of. I guess I could include my data equation in a try statement and except a KeyError...thanks, this has given me more to think about.

Comment: I'm not sure why you get that content type, it's not what the API is returning.